# Login to iOS app using Foursquare

Tags: ios, foursquare

Is there anyway to log in to foursquare in an app (not using a web view but the same way you log into facebook or google by installing frameworks/cocoapods)? I've been searching the web for a while and haven't found much help in that regards but I feel like there has to be a way.

I want to integrate user checkins into my app which gather's the nearest foursquare places.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why did someone down vote this? That was unnecessary.

Comment: It was down voted (by somebody else) because Stack Overflow is a place where people find help with specific programming questions, it's not a search engine.

Comment: Forgive me if I broke Stack Overflow etiquette but I see general questions like this (which does have to do with programming) all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon DasQuadrat framework/cocoapod after a bit more searching, it seems to be just what I was looking for.